# Voters for week only shows one user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, users-page

Today after being inspired by the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) to further increase my voting, I went out and voted some more.

Looking at [my profile page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/374/xiaohouzi79) on skeptics it says I have 4 for the week and 0 for today.

If I go to the [users voters link](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=week) for the week it only shows one user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a cut-off before users show on these pages.

For the voters tab, it is 10 votes.
For the edits tab, it is 5 edits.

Comment: I don't have any official comment, but looking at SO, it looks like it is > 10 votes per week, starting from Sunday.